# How to add a number of objects skipping nil objects to NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I need a method that would add a few objects (2-10) to my array, skipping these that are nils:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[arr addObjectsSkipNils:obj1, obj2, obj3];
```

How I can write this method in an elegant way?

Comment: Array object contains nil or [NSNull Null]?

Comment: Each of the objects is either nil or a real object. I just don't want to write 3 statements, can it be done with 1?

Comment: Can't be done that way, even (especially) with non-nil values.  The last value in the list must always be nil.

Comment: (Can be done with one long, tortuous statement using `?:`, but I'd hardly advise it.  Sometimes you actually have to write more than one statement.  (Be thankful you're not doing it in assembler.))

Comment: I could add the nil objects to dictionary, than filter out nils - but this is not nice...

Comment: I'd like to see you try to add the nils.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This category method would work:

```
@interface NSMutableArray (MyAdditions)
- (void)addObjectsSkipNilsWithCount:(NSUInteger)count objects:(id)obj, ...;
@end

@implementation NSMutableArray (MyAdditions)

- (void)addObjectsSkipNilsWithCount:(NSUInteger)count objects:(id)obj, ...
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, obj);
    // First object:
    if (obj != nil)
        [self addObject:obj];
    // Remaining objects:
    for (NSUInteger i = 1; i < count; i++) {
        id myobj = va_arg(ap, id);
        if (myobj != nil)
            [self addObject:myobj];
    }
    va_end(ap);
}
@end
```

Example:

```
NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray array];
[a addObjectsSkipNilsWithCount:3 objects:@"foo", nil, @"bar"];
NSLog(@"%@", a);
// Output: ( foo, bar )
```

You have to specify the number of objects explicitly, because `nil` cannot be used as terminator for the variable argument list. (And bad things can happen if the count is greater than the actual number of objects supplied !)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
[yourMainArray removeObjectIdenticalTo:[NSNull null]];
```

Now if you want to copy this to `arr` you can do quite easily.

Comment: How did the nil values get into the array in the first place?

Comment: Yes, this is a chicken-and-egg problem.